# Redirect after login_required loses POST parameters

Tags: django, authentication

I have a view that looks something like this simplified example:

```py
@decorators.login_required()
def add_data(request):
    some_value = request.POST['some_value']
    # do stuff.
```

If a user is authenticated already, this completes successfully. If the user is not authenticated, this redirects to the login page. After the login page, the POST request is sent back to my add_data view is missing `some_value` and all other POST data.

Is this expected? Is there a way to access the POST data?

I am using the default django.contrib.auth.views.login. I have a custom login.html.

Comment: I am planning to require login before accessing the form that posts this data, but I am still curious about what the best practice is here.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this expected?

Yes.

> Is there a way to access the POST data?

Probably not, the anonymous user and logged in user will have separate sessions so that won't work.

You might be able to some how store the data in a `GET` variable and pass it to the login form, and then inspect that.

I'd suggest its just a case where the user has messed up, and they should check they are logged in before submitting things.